# Index is not used when replace function is used on indexed column

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a sql query on table with mobileno column mobileno contains "-" so in where clause i need to use replace(mobileno,"-","") function for comparision.
With explain function i checked that it doesn't use index if function is used on indexed column. So how can i force sql to used index or any other alternative to increase my query performance.

Comment: Yes that is not going to use the index while you use this kind of string function on where clause and this is same for using date functions on where clause. You may need to create an additional column in the table to keep the numbers without - and index that column or update the existing table, then run the query on the column.

Comment: Yes we were also thinking the same but the database is very huge further it will be a major change, Isn't there any other way apart from this.

Comment: I dont think so, but you can have a look at regex if that helps but I doubt it will.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the index is not used because of the REPLACE function? Maybe there's not enough rows to make using an index worthwhile. Or some other reason.

I ran a test with 4256 rows and to my surprise, an index was used, even with REPLACE:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT mobileno FROM test WHERE REPLACE(mobileno, '(', '') = '123) 456-789'

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key         key_len ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE      test    index   NULL            mobileno    768     NULL    4256    100         "Using where; Using index"
```